# Updating subdirectory in globals.php

Tags: php, global

I moved my site from the root directory to a subdirectory called /portal. However, all of the links, css scripts, and images are linking as if the site is still in the root.

My website is http://thespartaninstitute.com/portal

The script developer said that this can be edited in the globals.php section. I don't know PHP though. Could you guys help me out on what I should edit? Thanks! Below are what I believe are the relevant lines in the PHP file.

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
define('REAL_PUBLIC_PATH',dirname(realpath(__FILE__)));#getcwd()); // e.g. /home/user/public_html
define("PHP_DIR",REAL_PUBLIC_PATH."/../../ClixScript_PHP_DOCS/"); // DEFINE THE PATH TO your ClixScript_PHP_DOCS folder here...
define('STORAGE_DIR',PHP_DIR.'storage/');
define("PHP_ERRORS_DIR",@constant("STORAGE_DIR")."err/PHP_errors.log");
define("START_MICROTIME",microtime(true));
define('REAL_PUBLIC_DIR',basename(getcwd())); // e.g public_html
define('RUN_HOOK',PHP_DIR.'runHook.php');
define('ASSET_POINTS',0);
define('ASSET_CASH',1); // USD
define('ASSET_TE_CREDITS',250); // Traffic Exchange Credits
define('CONTROLLER_DIR',constant("PHP_DIR").'controller/');

#define('PLUGIN_DIR',constant("PHP_DIR").'plugins/');


@set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
// DO NOT USE MAGIC QUOTES, this method will deal with those who still use it, but it's faster to just turn it off
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
/** Includes : */
if(defined('INCLUDES') AND INCLUDES === TRUE)
{
// Create array of all classes, their path and filenames (only to be used in __autoload later).
$classes = getDirectory(PHP_DIR.'classes');

foreach ($classes as $path=>$v)
{
    foreach($v as $file)
    {
        $files[] = $file;
        $paths[] = $path;
    }
}
// We need global variables to use in __autoload later...
$GLOBALS['classes_file_names'] = &$classes_file_names; 
$classes_file_names = $files;
$GLOBALS['classes_paths'] = &$classes_paths;
$classes_paths = $paths;

function __autoload($class_name)
{

    $classes_paths = $GLOBALS['classes_paths'];
    $classes_file_names = $GLOBALS['classes_file_names'];

    $filename = strtolower('class.'.$class_name.'.php');

    if(($key = array_search($filename,$classes_file_names)) !== false)
    {
        require_once $classes_paths[$key]."/".$filename;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }    
}


require_once PHP_DIR."config/config.php";

define('CUSTOM_CONTROLLER_DIR',constant("REAL_PUBLIC_PATH").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'portal/view/theme/'.trim(Vars::$conf->site->template).'/ctr/');

$time_zone = Vars::$conf->site->time_zone;
// if time zone has been specified:
if(!empty($time_zone) and strpos($time_zone,'/') !== false)
{
    // set default to it:
    date_default_timezone_set($time_zone);
}

}

if(defined('INCLUDE_PLUGINS') AND INCLUDE_PLUGINS === TRUE)
{

    define('PLUGIN_DIR',constant("REAL_PUBLIC_PATH").'/plugins/');
    define('PLUGIN_URL',Router::getHost().'plugins/');
/**
 * Load plugins (START)
 */ 
$plugins = Plugins::getAllPluginNames();

$classes = array();

foreach($plugins as $plugin)
{
    $path = PLUGIN_DIR.$plugin.'/classes';

    $res = getDirectory($path);
    if(!empty($res))
    {
        $classes[$path] = $res[$path];    
    }
}

foreach ($classes as $path=>$v)
{
    foreach($v as $file)
    {
        $files[] = $file;
        $paths[] = $path;
    }
}

// We need global variables to use in __autoload later...
$classes_file_names = array_merge($classes_file_names,$files);
$classes_paths = array_merge($classes_paths,$paths);


// Load Kohana Classes, start
define('SYSPATH',true);

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/kohana/Exception.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/Exception.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/kohana/Arr.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/Arr.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/kohana/pagination.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/pagination.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/DB.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/DB.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Result.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Result.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Exception.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Exception.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/MySQL/Result.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/MySQL.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Query.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Query.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Query/Builder.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Query/Builder.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Query/Builder/Where.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Query/Builder/Where.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Query/Builder/Delete.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Query/Builder/Delete.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Query/Builder/Insert.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Query/Builder/Insert.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Query/Builder/Join.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Query/Builder/Join.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Query/Builder/Select.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Query/Builder/Select.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Query/Builder/Update.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Query/Builder/Update.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Kohana/Database/Expression.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/MySQL.php';
include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/MySQL/Result.php';

include PHP_DIR.'classes/kohana/database/classes/Database/Expression.php';

// Load Kohana Classes, end

// Load vendors:
include PHP_DIR.'vendor/facebook/base_facebook.php';
include PHP_DIR.'vendor/facebook/facebook.php';
include PHP_DIR.'vendor/phpQuery/phpQuery-onefile.php';

// Load plugins
Plugins::load();
// Set routes for all plugins (will not overwrite these already specified in config)
Plugins::runMethod('routes');


/**
 * Load plugins (END)
 */ 
 }
 else
 {
  #  exit;
 }

Config::$language = 'us';
// If user has chosen language, set it:
if(isset($_COOKIE['language_code']))
{
    if(in_array($_COOKIE['language_code'],array_keys(Config::$valid_languages)))
    {
        Config::$language = $_COOKIE['language_code'];
    }
}
// If user has not set language, detect country of user and choose language based on that:
if(!isset($_COOKIE['language_code']))
{
    $ip2c = new Ip2Country;
    $ip2c->load(User::getRealIP());
    $country = strtolower($ip2c->countryCode);

    if(in_array($country,array_keys(Config::$valid_languages)))
    {
        $expire=60*60*24*365*10;    
        setcookie('language_code',$country,(time()+$expire),'/');
        Config::$language = $country;
    }
}
#$GLOBALS['sidebar_menu'] = $sidebar_menu;
if(!defined('ONLY_GLOBALS'))
{
    include PHP_DIR.'config/variables.php';
}
/**
 * Functions:
 */ 

function getDirectory($path = '.', $ignore = null) {

    $default_ignore = array('.htaccess', 'error_log', 'cgi-bin', 'php.ini', '.ftpquota');
    if($ignore === null) $ignore = $default_ignore;
    else $ignore = array_merge($default_ignore,$ignore);

    $dirTree = array ();
    $dirTreeTemp = array ();
    $ignore[] = '.';
    $ignore[] = '..';

    $dh = @opendir($path);

    if($dh !== false)
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {

            if (!in_array($file, $ignore)) {
                if (!is_dir("$path/$file")) {

                    $dirTree["$path"][] = $file;

                } else {

                    $dirTreeTemp = getDirectory("$path/$file", $ignore);
                    if (is_array($dirTreeTemp))$dirTree = array_merge($dirTree, $dirTreeTemp);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }

    return $dirTree;
}



class ErrorHandling
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->doer();
    }

    public function doer()
    {
        ob_start(array(&$this, 'fatalErrorHandler'));
        set_error_handler(array(&$this, 'errorHandler'));
    }

    public function logError($str)
    {
        $errpath = constant("PHP_ERRORS_DIR");
        $handle = fopen($errpath,"a+");
        fwrite($handle,$str."\r\n");
        fclose($handle);
    }

    public function fatalErrorHandler($buffer)
    {
      if(ereg("(error</b>:)(.+)(<br)", $buffer, $regs))
        {
        $err = preg_replace("/<.*?>/","",$regs[2]);
            $time = "[".Time::unixReadable()."]";
            $this->logError($time.' Fatal Error:'.$err.' [SCRIPT TERMINATED]');
            return "Fatal error occured, execution halted";
      }
      return $buffer;
    }

    public function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        $time = "[".Time::unixReadable()."]";
        if($errno != 2048 && $errno != 0)
        {
            switch($errno)
            {
                case 256:
                    $str = $time.' E_USER_ERROR ['.$errno.'] '.$errstr.' in file '.$errfile.'('.$errline.') [SCRIPT TERMINATED]';
                    break;
                case 512:
                    $str = $time.' E_USER_WARNING ['.$errno.'] '.$errstr.' in file '.$errfile.'('.$errline.')';
                break;
                case 8:
                    $str = $time.' E_USER_NOTICE ['.$errno.'] '.$errstr.' in file '.$errfile.'('.$errline.')';
                break;
                default:
                    $str = $time.' Unknown error type ['.$errno.'] '.$errstr.' in file '.$errfile.'('.$errline.')';
                break;
            }
            $this->logError($str);
        }
        elseif($errno == "FATAL" || $errno == "ERROR")
        {
            $this->logError($time.' Fatal Error ['.$errno.'] '.$errstr.' in file '.$errfile.'('.$errline.') [SCRIPT TERMINATED]');
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Search that PHP file in your `/portal` folder that contains/generates the `<HEAD>` part of your HTML page, because your includes are there.
As I can see your HTML source, you have 5-6 CSS and JavaScript include. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thespartaninstitute.com/view/theme/thespartaninstitute/css/layout.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thespartaninstitute.com/view/theme/thespartaninstitute/css/jquery.qtip.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thespartaninstitute.com/view/theme/thespartaninstitute/css/niceforms-default.css" media="all" />
```

These should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thespartaninstitute.com/portal/view/theme/thespartaninstitute/css/layout.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thespartaninstitute.com/portal/view/theme/thespartaninstitute/css/jquery.qtip.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thespartaninstitute.com/portal/view/theme/thespartaninstitute/css/niceforms-default.css" media="all" />
```

You should add `/portal/` after your domain name at every include path.
If these includes are in plain HTML than just simply type `/portal/` after your domain.

If there is a PHP variable or defined constant then you have to change that or as I mentioned before simply write `/portal/` after your domain name.
For example if you see something like this:

```
echo SITE_ROOT.'view/theme/thespartaninstitute/css/layout.css';
```

Then change it to:

```
echo SITE_ROOT.'/portal/view/theme/thespartaninstitute/css/layout.css';
```

Or search the `define` of `SITE_ROOT` and add `/portal/` to it end. In this case I would suggest the first solution.

If there is a variable or a constant that contains more than just the site root like these:

```
echo THEME_INCLUDE_PATH.'css/layout.css';
```

Then find `THEME_INCLUDE_PATH` in your `globals.php` and add `/portal/` after your domain there.

Comment: Thanks for all of that! I don't want to manually change the includes because that would create problems for my site designer.

Comment: However, I did find this in the globals. Is this what you're talking about? And, if so, how should I edit it?

define('CUSTOM_CONTROLLER_DIR',constant("REAL_PUBLIC_PATH").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'view/theme/'.trim(Vars::$conf->site->template).'/ctr/');

Comment: Do you think if we change the real public path, or the real public directory, that that might fix it?

Comment: Maybe, but it will effect every variable and code that based on that constant, so it can cause unwanted side effects. Please try my general approach to find the needed constant or edit your question and add the whole/mayor part of the code in `globals.php`.

Comment: I edited it and added the entire globals.php code. Sorry, I'm new to PHP so this is blowing my mind, heh.

Comment: I red the code but I have only guesses, can't give you a 100% solution. I need to see the `index.php` and files included by that. In this case I would suggest you to copy all `.css` and `.js` ending files to the root directory until your programmer correct the problem. This must fix the problem bacause the include paths will point to an existing file.